# Listview with section headers are not updating when data changes

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to update a listview with section headers, but the view isn't changing:
https://rnplay.org/apps/WJ1cEw

Here's the code where I am trying to update the listview:

```
changeData(){
    var dataTemp = Object.assign({},data);
    dataTemp.Section1[0] = {title: 'New content for Row 1, Section 1'};
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataTemp)
    });
}
```

I can see that rowHasChanged is running, but row1 and row2 both contain the new data so it never evaluates to true.

If I always return true from rowHasChanged the ListView is updated, but I guess that means the entire listView is rerendered.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Specifically, where is "data" coming from?  I bet it's being modified by ref and so it's already changed because it's certainly not set in this "changeData" function.

Comment: I provided a complete example with source code in the rnplay link above.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not returning anything from your rowHasChanged function:

```
    this.state = {
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged : (row1, row2) => {
                console.log(row1.title + ' ' + row2.title);
                return row1 !== row2; // <--- MISSING RETURN
            },
            sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
        })
    };
```

Second, `Object.assign` is a shallow merge.  You have arrays in there which are being stomped on by ref just the same despite your attempt to make `changeData` pure.  Best option is to compute your sections based on the flat list of real data every time you call changeData rather than storing the sections as part of state, but otherwise if you want to just get it working you could do a deep clone first with [lodash.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

```
changeData(){
    data = _.cloneDeep(data)

    data.Section1[0] = {title: 'New content for Row 1, Section 1'};
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)
    });
}
```

The better approach I mentioned would use Array.prototype.reduce:

```
const data = data.reduce((blob, dataItem) => {
    const section = 'ComputedSectionLabel';
    blob[section] = blob[section] || [];
    blob[section].push(dataItem);
}, {});

this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)
});
```